# ActionBar убивает приложение

Tags: java, android, actionbar

Стоит буквально прописать

```
ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
```

или

```
actionBar.setTitle("Заголовок");
```

и приложение перестает работать. Или вылетает с той активности, где это прописано. Кстати, стандартный черный или светлый `ActionBar` работает нормально, если прописать

```
MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

а вот настраиваемый никак.
В манифесте указана тема `AppTheme` (в styles его parent `Theme.AppCompat`...).
Если полностью удалить тему из манифеста, тогда свой `ActionBar` работает нормально, но тогда все другие стили в приложении слетают.

В SDK установил все, что только можно. Ничего не помогает. Использую AndroidStudio.

Как мне задать свой `ActionBar`?

Answer (score 4):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); 
actionBar.setTitle("Заголовок");
```

Comment: Перевожу: @katso хотел сказать, что ваша версия Android не поддерживает `ActionBar` без саппорт библиотек.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Toolbar. У toolbar есть метод setTitle. В теме, которую Вы прописали в application в поле parent пропишите `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.
А в activity найдите toolbar через findViewById и сделайте `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` . Ваша активити должна быть наследником AppCompatActivity